# Spark job submiited from local machine to remore cluster can't see data on remote server

Tags: apache-spark

The post may seem a bit long but I am providing all the specific details to help readers what I am trying to achieve and what all I have already done but still running into issue.

I am trying to submit the spark job to remote cluster from eclipse running locally on windows 7 machine but running into issue with respect to finding the input path to data on cluster nodes. I followed the suggestion made in this forum to configure the sparkContext as following where I set the spark.driver.host to IP address of Windows machine.

```
            SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Count Lines")
                                    .set("spark.driver.host", "9.1.194.199")  //IP address of Windows 7
                    .set("spark.driver.port", "51910")
                    .set("spark.fileserver.port", "51811")
                    .set("spark.broadcast.port", "51812")
                    .set("spark.replClassServer.port", "51813")
                    .set("spark.blockManager.port", "51814")
                            .setMaster("spark://master.aa.bb.com:7077"); //mater hostname
```

I also had to set HADOOP_HOME to c:\winutils in eclipse, to be able to run this code on windows.
Then I set the path to data which exists on all the nodes of spark cluster as following

```
            String topDir = "/data07/html/test";
                    JavaRDD<String> lines = sc.textFile(topDir+"/*");
```

However, I get following error.

```
5319 [main] INFO  org.apache.spark.SparkContext  - Created broadcast 0 from textFile at CountLines2.java:65
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input Pattern file:/data07/html/test/* matches 0 files
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:251)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:270)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:201)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:205)
```

Now considering the fact that running the code inside eclipse needed local hadoop installation (ie., setting HADOOP_HOME to c:\winutils), I modified the code to use a data path that exists locally on Windows machine. With that modification, the progam went a bit further and  launched tasks on all the nodes of the cluster but failed later for path issue with a different error.

```
105926 [task-result-getter-2] INFO  org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager  - Lost task 15.2 in stage 0.0 (TID 162) on executor master.aa.bb.com: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException (java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: C:%5Cdata%5CMedicalSieve%5Crepositories%5Craw%5CMedscape%5Cclinical/*) [duplicate 162]
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 44 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 44.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 148, aalim03.almaden.ibm.com): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: C:%5Cdata%5Chtml%5Ctest/*
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.initialize(Path.java:206)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.<init>(Path.java:172)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.StringUtils.stringToPath(StringUtils.java:241)
```

Answer (score 0):

As a rule of thumb every input you use should be accessible on every node (both workers and driver). These could be local file system, files on some DFS or external resource.

The only situation when data is shipped directly from the driver is when you use `ParallelCollectionRDD` with `parallelize` / `makeRDD`.

Comment: Why does driver need access to the data? The workers do the actual processing of the data so I am bit unclear why is that needed?

Comment: Well, someone has to tell the workers what to do and to be able to do it has to know what is the job.

Comment: could you please elaborate. Isn't what workers need to do is known to them through the driver code? why driver node needs to access the input that is used for RDD?